# Changes instant edits to suggested edits

Tags: feature-request

Users with 2000 or more rep can instantly make edits without going through the review process. No one should be able to do that, since the review phase is a good chance for quality assurance, that all edits are on par.

Comment: Is this a real issue? Is there any particular example of 2k user making harmful edit which was not reverted quickly by another user?

Comment: I have seen a few edit wars happen. Only reason they are possible is because all users involved can instantly edit things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

And any other 2k user can revert those edits. Any edit bumps the post to the frontpage, ensuring that it will be seen by other users. This works well enough that I don't see any reason to require explicit review by other users. This would just require a lot more work, with very little benefit.

Comment: Fair enough, I just think a good review system would be better than allowing any experienced user to edit freely.